# Is there a way to subset in R for a large dataset where you can filter every instance of a variable?

Tags: r, subset

The issue I have is that I want to create dataframes for individual countries. I have a relatively large dataset, one of the columns is countries so I need to have every instance country x and then all other variables.

When I try to subset I *Subset[name, country ="X"]* it says that X isnt found. The other option would be name[1:2,], but the issue here is the dataset is so large it is hard to find the vectors needed.

The key thing is that I need all veriables for every instance of country X as they reoccur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata <- data.frame(country = rep(c("NL", "BE"), 2), value = 9:12)

library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
# split by country, create a named list
L <- split(mydata, by = "country")
# pass list's content to current environment, based on list's names
list2env(L, envir = environment())
```

[image]